# sql format function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute the following query, but i get an error that the function format does not exist.

```
CREATE TABLE [prods](
    [Id] [int] not null,
    [ShippedDate] [datetime] not null,
    [shipId] AS (format([ShippedDate], 'yyMM','en-US') +right('00000' + CONVERT([varchar],[Id]).(6)))
)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `FORMAT` was introduced with SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FORMAT` function is only available in SQL Server 2012+.

Formatting dates in 2008 and earlier is a bit cumbersome. You can do

```
RIGHT(CAST(YEAR([ShippedDate]) AS NVARCHAR(4)), 2) 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH([ShippedDate]) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

to get a string consisting of two digit year plus two digit month.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function of the version of SQL `FORMAT` is available in SQL Server 2012 and Later